# What does (jd) and (i, field) mean?

Tags: jquery, json, function

I have just startet learning jQuery and JSON. 
I have wondered about what **(jd)** means in this context:

$.getJSON('/jquery/result.json', function(jd)

And what about **"(i, field)"** in this context?

$.each(result, function(i, field)

Is "i" just a symbol of Integer? 
And what about field, can anyone explain to me, what is means?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: They could all be whatever you want as long as you change the code inside to match the variable names. You could call it `stackoverflow` or `facebook` or `myspace` or `qwerty881273777773jjajja`. It's just a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

`jd` is the name that the author of that code gave to the argument that the callback receives when the JSON request is complete; see [`$.getJSON` for details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON). It will be the deserialized object.

`i` and `field` are the names the author of that code gave to the arguments that jQuery calls the iterator function (callback) with, which are the index of the thing in the array, and the value of the thing. So for instance, if `result` contains 10 things, the first call to the callback will receive `i = 0` and `field = result[0]`; the second call to the callback will receive `i = 1` and `field = result[1]`, and so on. See [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) for details.

It's well worth spending an hour reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('/jquery/result.json', function(jd)
```

in the above case `jd` is the ajax(json) result returned by the `$.getJSON` call. you can put anything instead `jd` like this..

```
$.getJSON('/jquery/result.json', function(result) 

$.each(result, function(i, field)
```

in the `$.each` case `i` refers to the index and the `field` refers to the elements inside `result` . you can also out anything same like above..